# Something wrong with my for loop

Tags: c++, stl

I declared a vector and looped over it but I get a strange behavior.

```
vector<int> neg;  #size of neg vector becomes two afterwards
int k=2           #k is 2 too
for(int i=neg.size()-1;i>=neg.size()-k;--i){
           --do-something-with-the-value-of-vector-elements--
}
```

This leads to seg vault subsequently.

But when I change the for loop to:

```
int st=neg.size()-k;

for(int i=neg.size()-1;i>=st;--i){
           --do-something-with-the-value-of-vector-elements--
}
```

This works perfectly fine. I think this is some issue with the unsigned and signed element addition but I am not sure. I am missing something here. Can someone please explain?

Comment: You need cast neg.size() to the int.

Comment: I know what is wrong; it's a numerical for loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`neg.size()` is not int but `size_t`, that's unsigned, and neg.size()-k can overflow, so i<= will always be true.

If you want to use signed arithmetic, use `i>=int(neg.size())-k`, or stay in the unsigned domain, writing `i+k>=neg.size()`, declaring k as size_t.